# Mopria SDK for Android devices?

Tags: android, printing

At present, Android Default Print Service’s core printing technology comes from the Mopria Print Service.
Is there a Mopria SDK available like AirPrint SDK for iOS? Alternatively, can we extend the Android default print service to develop our custom print service?

I searched all over the internet for a repository containing Mopria SDK, but all I could find is the Mopria site where they have only provided content about the Mopria capabilities.